# Java - I've got a library(.a/.so) and header(.h), how to use Java call their functions?

Tags: java, c++, linux, ubuntu, .a

Someone sent me his static library(lib.a) and a header file(lib.h) it should be written in C++, I've used gcc compiler to convert the static library(lib.a) into a shared library(.so). Now I want to use Java to call library to use it's functions.

I have tried System.load and System.loadLibrary but I don't know how to call it's functions. For example, I've see there is a function call MoveFront(int) from the header file and it will return the integer for the status.

```
extern int MoveFront(int);
```

There's a way to do that? Thank you.

I am using Ubuntu 13.10, JDK 1.8.0_20, gcc 4.6.3.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md

Comment: But JNA does not support C++. In that case there are other similar tools such as [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco) that work with C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not call them directly in Java

You have to build a bridge using JNI

link your lib.a with bridge.c into libbridge.so 
then, java can use `System.loadLibrary("bridge")` to use it

some guide here https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html